# How to use Pillow to display an image?

Tags: python, libraries

Edit:
It might help to know that I'm using python 2.7.9 (that's what was taught in my GIS class).
I've almost got it working I think. Although now it's a new question.
I have this code

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("C:/users/Chrostopher/Asuna.png")
```

There are no error messages and my screen flashed black like it wanted to do something, but the picture didn't show/open/display. What should I do?

Thanks for all the help so far. I feel like I'm slowly (and with many mistakes) learning something useful.
Old:
I am very, very new at this, which is why I'm asking. I've looked around for help, but there's always one thing I don't understand and it's just turned into a very deep rabbit hole.
When I've tried the code I've seen here, it doesn't work. Looking further, I need the Python Image Library (PIL). I've downloaded it, but I can't figure out how to set it up to work in Python. The file is a .gz. Is there some place I need to put the file or some way to import it?
If you could answer step by step, that would be wonderful for this extreme newb.

This is the code I have (to try and open an image which is the end goal)

```
import Image
def main():
    filename = "desert.jpg"
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.show
    del image

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Is there something I'm missing or not doing right that is messing up what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you install 'pip', you can use this package manager to install python libraries. Your system may already have it

Comment: Here is a tutorial for installing Python packages. See the pip + virtual environments part: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: You've unzipped the `.gz` file, right? That's step 1...

Comment: This has nothing to do with import libraries, but image.show without paranthesis doesn't do anything ... you almost certainly want image.show()  Also, you don't  need to use del 99.99% of the time.  Python isn't C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install Pillow with "pip"

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

Then, instead writing

```
import Image
```

In the first line, you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Assuming they're using Pillow and not PIL.

Comment: I did this `code` from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("C:/users/Chrostopher/Asuna.png") and it's almost working see the edited main description for the problem. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I have this `code`

    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open("C:/users/Chrostopher/Asuna.png")
end`code`
When I ran the code, there were no error messages and my screen flashed black like it wanted to do something, but the picture didn't show/open/display. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or need to do?

Comment: Maybe the image is flashing up very fast and then the program is exiting. At the beginning of the file add a new line that reads "from time import sleep". After the line with Image.open add a new line that reads "sleep(5)". This will pause your code for 5 seconds so you can see if the image really opened or not.

Comment: Hm, it only flashed black the first time I ran the code (without your fixes), now it just pauses 5 seconds (which is good to know, thanks). Do I need to have something to allow it to display? I'm working in the shell btw, not an .exe if that makes a difference.

Comment: I added im.show() after im = Image.open(filename) and that worked. It opened in windows photo viewer (which is the default program I have set). Thanks for all the help.